# EAGL: What does it stand for exactly?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I forget, but does EAGL stand for anything specific?  Or is it just part of the Core Animation OpenGL naming convention (CAEAGLLayer, etc.)?

Answer (score 46):

"AGL" is the name of Apple's OpenGL extensions for OS X.  I believe "EAGL" is an abbreviation for "Embedded AGL" or "ES AGL.

Alternatively, EAGL is Apple's version of [EGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EGL_(OpenGL)). "EGL" officially refers to the "Khronos Native Platform Graphics Interface", but earlier versions of the spec referred to it as "Embedded-System Graphic Library". So perhaps the correct answer is that EAGL means "Embedded-System Apple Graphics Library".

Answer (score 1):

might be Apple's Embedded Graphics Library

Answer (score -1):

http://db-in.com/blog/2011/02/khronos-egl-and-apple-eagl/

"..t the EGL API and the EAGL (the EGL API implemented by Apple)..."