# What's the difference in openGL and EAGL / openAL?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

Sometimes I read EAGL, openAL ... wikipedia doesn't tell me something about EAGL.

Comment: This is very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492551/eagl-what-does-it-stand-for-exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[openAL](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/default.aspx) is an Audio Library as opposed to a graphics Library.

[EAGL](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html) is an iPhone utility for using openGL ES, which is a version of openGL for Embedded Systems.